# Using Scala's Play & Slick with two form (validation & insertion)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

This is what I got:

**Controller**

```
val form = Form(
  mapping(
    "id" -> optional(number),
    "name" -> optional(nonEmptyText),
    "supID" -> number,
    "price" -> longNumber)(Coffee.apply)(Coffee.unapply) )

val extraForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "coffeeId" -> number,
    "amountOfDrinkers" -> number 
  )(Extra.apply)(Extra.unapply) )

 def showForm = Action { implicit request =>
   Ok(views.html.show_form(form, extraForm)
 }

//And then form validation & insertion

def save = Action { implicit request =>
 form.bindFromRequest.fold(
  // The second parameter for createForm would supposly pass the second form
  // with or without errors 
  formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.coffees.createForm(formWithErrors, /*secondForm?*/ )),
  entity => {
    database withTransaction {
      Coffees.insert(entity) 
      // So far we have worked & inserted the val form
      // But how can I also work & inser the extraForm ?
    }
  })
```

}

**1.** How can I have an extra input within the same form (e.g. foreign key) that will be verified & inserted to a different table?

**2.** id is optional and I defined it as Option in the case class. Is there a chance someone can modify the Post & insert into the id (there is no id input), in the model it is set as the PrimaryKey & AutoIncrease and I  want to prevent any external alteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with Play form handling but

Regarding 1:
Instead of `(Coffee.apply)(Coffee.unapply)` you could use something like `({ case (a,b,c,d) => (Coffee(a,b),OtherRow(c,d)) })({ case (Coffee(a,b),OtherRow(c,d)) => (a,b,c,d) })` to separate fields into different entities.

And later `Coffees.insert(entity._1); OtherTable.insert(entity._2)`

Regarding 2:
HTTP requests like POST are user input, which you can't trust. Make sure that whatever comes in does not misbehave. First, make sure you do NOT insert into the * projection, but into a separate one, which does not include the id column. Then nobody can insert an id. (The computer-database sample in play-slick is a bad example for this at the moment, because it uses * to define autoInc.) You can find an updated (but also more abstract) example here https://github.com/cvogt/play-slick/blob/93ecc12e60c7dcaf470e7886c50fd312ea5575fa/samples/computer-database/app/models/schema.scala

Second, you may want to make sure, that the form for creating coffees does not include an id field. Or if having an id field buys you something significant, like re-usability of the form, then verify in case of inserts, that it is set to None.

Comment: +1 for the example, although as an absolute beginner I find it a bit complicated.